# Adding rules to checkValidity()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add validation rules to my input fields. Currently I'm using this script to verify the form for required fields:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict'

  var forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation')

  Array.prototype.slice.call(forms).forEach(function(form) {
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      if (!form.checkValidity()) {
        event.preventDefault()
        event.stopPropagation()
      }
      form.classList.add('was-validated')
    }, false)
  })
})()
```

How can I add rules for each input inside this validation? I'm using jQuery library (I know the current script is pure javaScript).

Comment: You can just add required attribute to input fields like: `<input required>`. If you want additional functionality, like adding messages, colors etc, you either have to target each input individually for customized errors / results per input or loop through all input fields for a general message / color that can apply to all those fields.

Comment: I need validation for max and min length and also for the letters and numbers. I know how to easily do this by jQuery validation plugin but I'll lose the effect of this script. To be honest I like how it works.

Comment: A couple of questions: 1. the code indicates several forms, true? 2. If true, how to you expect to establish rules for the various input elements of each of the forms (presumably these would be different).

Comment: You can use `min`, `max` and `pattern` attributes on the input elements.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Yes it is used for several forms. I'll separate them when I find a way of doing what I want. Yeah, I can use `min`, `max` and `pattern`, but that's browser default alerts which looks ugly, I need custom styling and messages.

Comment: If you want precise and full control, you need to target each input individually (add a unique id to them so you can use `getElementById`). Then use Regex to define exact rules for that field. Keep in mind that Javascript is client side though. It can easily be bypassed. Secure validation should ALWAYS be done server side.

Comment: You said "_I need validation for max and min length and also for the letters and numbers_" - the simple answer is what I said: "_You can use min, max and pattern attributes on the input elements._"

Comment: MDN has a nice how-to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Constraint_validation

Comment: @RandyCasburn Actually your suggestion worked. When the input don't match the attribute rules the script is defining the input as invalid. Great!